# Facebook Like Button appear as 'Login Text'

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

Our client is having problem on FB Likebox button as she sees the button as 'Text' like the screenshot below:

[image]

The FB LikeBox should look like:

[image]

And also as she clicks the button an error pops-up:

[image]

I'm using Wordpress on the site: `http://www.thestyleinsider.co.nz/win-hottest-grill-planet/`

The client uses MAC. I tried it on Win 8, Ipad 2 and mobile, seems no problem with the button. Also my colleagues couldn't also replicate the issue.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a temporary problem from facebook , it has nothing to do with your code or the wordpress plugin you are using .

I had this problem several times for several facebook apps on my websites and it always gets fixed by itself .

I also visited your website using an iMAC and tested the plugin and it is working flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer. So you're saying that this is a facebook bug?

Comment: The weirdest thing about this issue is that i had the same "This app has not been setup properly" message , as i was trying to figure out the problem i reloaded the page and and the facebook app worked normally. Anyway what i think you should do is to recheck with your client to see if they are still having this issue , if so you can try to re add your app ID and token frm your facebook app into the plugin settings and finally if this also didn't work out you can try contacting facebook to get more details about this issue .

Comment: Thanks. I'm about to do that. Thumbs up for you answer.